# Follow symbol does not recognize SYCL functions and keywords in Qt creator

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator, sycl

I am using Qt creator 4.4.0 to develop a SYCL application. I am not able to follow the SYCL functions into the headers to check for their definitions in Qt like I can do with other standard headers which as vectors, set. Can someone please tell me what I am missing in the Qt project setup.

Here is the cmake for this simple project.

```
# CMakeLists for SYCL C++ Project

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "icpx")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/IntelSYCL/")
set(SYCL_LIBRARY_DIR "/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/lib")
set(SYCL_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/include/sycl/")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fsycl -fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda,spir64 -Xsycl-target-backend=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_75")

project(matrix_multiply_sycl LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(matrix_multiply_sycl matrix_multiply_sycl.cpp)
```

I am able to compile and run using this cmake lists file.

I have tried adding the SYCL lib include dir in the cmake and that still does not work. But Qt can auto recognize other std headers somehow.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with QtCreator, but I assume that the language server called underneath is `clangd`. Parsing DPC++ SYCL headers has only recently become possible with the DPC++ version of `clangd` as previous versions suffered from this issue: https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1097

The fix for this issue has not made it into any Intel oneAPI toolkit releases yet and it will take a few months until it does. If you don't want to wait, you could try building [open-source DPC++](https://github.com/intel/llvm) and use its `clang++` compiler driver (instead of `icpx` which is only available in the full Intel releases). Unfortunately the open-source binary releases don't include `clangd` so you'd need to build from source including `clang-tools-extra`.

Regardless of whether you use the open-source DPC++ or wait for an updated oneAPI toolkit release, you'd also need to make sure that QtCreator environment is set correctly such that it's using the DPC++ version of `clangd` and not any other version that might be available in your system. Using the [upstream LLVM `clangd`](https://clangd.llvm.org/) unfortunately won't work in the near future, as the SYCL support is specific to DPC++.